# mkdir options are not clear

Tags: linux, unix, mkdir

I just ran into this line:

```
mkdir /cache 0770 system cache
```

but didn't find on web what's the "system cache" mean.
0770 is the permission I guess, but this line doesn't look like something that suits what's described here:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir

edit:
sorry, these lines are in init.rc , I guess it's different then what I expected..
for example, in creating simbolic link here is "symlink" and not "ls -s".
what language is this ?

Comment: I think the commands is creating differents folders. mkdir dir_1 dir_2 dir_3 

So, you re creating a folder in the root folder of the OS, and 3 folder in ur actual folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mkdir in init.rc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559056/mkdir-in-init-rc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say in your edit, this is a line in a rc.init file which contains information for the init process on a *nix system. The "words"/fields have specified meanings. The first one is a "command" to the init process, but does not necessarily correspond to an existing binary or shell script in the path. Instead, it is a key word which specifies what the init process is to do. As the name suggests, the "mkdir" keyword instructs it to make a directory; but it could as well be named "makedirectory" or whatever. The specific syntax for it is

```
mkdir <path> [mode] [owner] [group]
```

In your example

```
mkdir /cache 0770 system cache
```

- the directory path is /cache (in the root directory)
- the mode is 0770 (give user and group all rights to read, write and execute; give anybody else no rights)
- make user "system" the owner
- make group "cache" the group.

For a list of possible init commands in android, cf. [this list](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/readme.txt).

Comment: still, what is the "system cache" ?